# How to prevent map function from returning null

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects called languages.
If language object have alpha2 it should return  { label: i.name, value: i.alpha2 } .
If it does't have alpha2 it should return null .

```
languages.all.map((i,index) =>  i.alpha2 ? { label: i.name, value: i.alpha2 } : null )
```

But if I pass this to my react component, I got an error undefined is not an object.
So I don't want pass null to array created by language.all.map I want to skip the process of passing something in the array.

How I can do this ?

Comment: `map` returns as many elements in the array as there were originally. You can use `filter` to remove `null` values or use `reduce` instead of `map`, inserting elements into the accumulator when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As map returns results for *every element in the calling array*, you can filter *null*:

```
languages.all.map((i,index) =>  i.alpha2 ? { label: i.name, value: i.alpha2 } : null )
             .filter(i => i);
```

**OR:** Even better with `reduce()` in a single iteration

```
languages.all.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (cur.alpha2) {
    var o = { label: cur.name, value: cur.alpha2 };
    acc.push(o);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```